# Forward Proxy Loadbalancer/failover

Tags: go, proxy

Please consider this design situation: I use two remote HTTP proxys,`http://proxy1:8181` and `http://proxy2:8282`, and have an app that does `GET` and `POST` to various external endpoints using one of these at a time.

These proxy endpoints have been randomly flaky, one at a time thankfully. I am looking for ways to use the working endpoint amongst these two. Sort of a failover mechanism.

Here's what I am looking to do: setup a deamon that listens on `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, and routinely check `proxy1` and `proxy2` in a loop. Then route incoming request using `proxy1` if it is healthy, if not use `proxy2`.

Easier said than done!

Not sure such a load balancer for Fwd Proxies exist - anyway, looking for pointers and any help will be appreciated!

I am looking to do this in Golang preferrably, next choice is C. To start with, this is not as simple as giving a `301`, also to appease SO's `show me the code so far`:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

const (
    port = "8000"
)

func main() {
    listen := ":" + port
    go http.HandleFunc("/", redir)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(listen, nil))
}

func redir(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("Hello there!")
    http.Redirect(w, r, "http://pi3/cameras/", 301)
}
```

As I see:

```
$ wget -e http_proxy="http://arrow:8000/" -S -O /dev/null http://moooh/cameras/ -d 
<snip>
  HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Location: http://pi3/cameras/
  Date: Sat, 12 Oct 2019 03:57:00 GMT
  Content-Length: 54
URI content encoding = ‘utf-8’
Location: http://pi3/cameras/ [following]
Skipping 54 bytes of body: [<a href="http://pi3/cameras/">Moved Permanently</a>.

] done.
URI content encoding = None
20 redirections exceeded. // <<<< 
<snip>
```

Comment: Issue  requests through a selected proxy server.  If a request fails because of a problem with the proxy server, then select the other proxy server and reissue the request through that server.

Comment: The problem is that no matter what, your code will always send a redirect. But as it is used as a proxy (as far as I understood), the next request will also get the same redirect. I assume that the two remote proxies are reverse proxies?